# Develop and debug angular7 project using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, ecmascript-6

I created a angular7 project using `ng new my-app` command (instruction given by https://angular.io/guide/setup-local).
I am a visual studio fan and I want to develop and debug this application further using visual studio 2017 **(not with visual studio code)**.

I tried following with visual studio.

> File -> Open -> Website (and opened the application folder)

[image]

but when I hit "Start Debugging" or "Start without Debugging" it goes to 
**"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden"** page
[image]

I know there is a separate option in visual studio to create Angular application but it will create a angular application with some c# and .net bindings. I don't need that and what I need is pure Angular7 app with pure HTML.

is there any configuration has to be done to debug and run the app through visual studio?

Comment: To debug typescript through a text editor you need a node server running with source maps=true. When you hit the debug button, visual studio would not do that by default. Also don’t go down this rabbit hole, just don’t do it to yourself. It isnt worth it in the end anyways. Visual studio code is amazing for angular development. Take it from a long time angular developer who works in both code editors, vscode is by far the better tool for the job. Learn the angular cli well because it can be your new best friend

Answer (score 2):

You can create Angular project with .Net Core using this template

[image]

[image]

And to debug typescript you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/debug-nodejs?view=vs-2019). Is pretty long so I cant pass the detail for you.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This way it will create a angular application with as a C#.netCore application with some .netCore bindings. What I need is just a pure html angular appliaction.

Comment: Then you can use Angular CLi

Answer (score 0):

open website folder path in CMD . type "npm start" . go to your File and type `debugger;`